# Select a particular column greater than certain condition and select grep word that mentioned in the file

Tags: awk, grep, cygwin

I have a files FB_Dataset.csv simply contains 21 columns, whereas FB_Dataset.csv is a comma delimited file. The general scheme of FB_Dataset.csv is posted below.

[image]

I need to extract the word 'Trump' (Ignore case) mentioned in the file and number of likes (10th column) greater than 100. And finally generate a new file with post_id (2nd column) and sorted like_count (10th column) and name it “trump.txt”.

I'm new to unix and learned that to extract the 2 conditions separately. The code would probably be **grep -i -o 'Trump' FB_Dataset.csv** for first condition and **awk '$10 > 100{print}' FB_Dataset.csv** for the second condition. What should i do next?

Thank you

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.
   **This appears to be a CSV file, so copy-paste some or all of the text file rather than a screenshot of the file loaded into a spreadsheet.**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need

```
awk -F, '/[tT]rump/ && $3>100' FB_Dataset.csv | sort -t, -k 3,3n > trump.txt
```

Searching for "trump" and numbers greater than 100 is done by `awk`, final sorting is performed by `sort` numerically on the third column (`-k 3,3n`). The switches `-F,` and `-t,` are needed to use comma as a delimiter.